# child div with relative height in parent div with relative height

Tags: html, css

I have a **parent div that creates a grey layer** and a **inner child div that contains the text which should be scrollable**.

**Problem:** the child div doesnt consider the max-height 100% and thsu overruns the parent div and doesnt become scrollable.

**Note:** *I know it can be fixed if the parent or child div is set in absolute values (pixels), but I want both to be dynamic and adjust to browser size.*

Does anyone have a solution to this?

```css
#dataprotection-window {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 85%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5%;
  background: #2f2f2f;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#datainner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#dataprotection-window::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#dataprotection-headline h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

#dataprotection-window p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
}

#dataprotection-window h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-margin-after: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="dataprotection-window">
    <div id="datainner">
      <div id="dataprotection-headline">
        <h1>Datenschutz</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="dataprotection-disclaimer">
        <h2>Datenschutz</h2>
        <p>Die Betreiber dieser Seiten nehmen den Schutz Ihrer persönlichen Daten sehr ernst. Wir behandeln Ihre personenbezogenen Daten vertraulich und entsprechend der gesetzlichen Datenschutzvorschriften sowie dieser Datenschutzerklärung. Die Nutzung
          unserer Website ist in der Regel ohne Angabe personenbezogener Daten möglich. Soweit auf unseren Seiten personenbezogene Daten (beispielsweise Name, Anschrift oder E-Mail-Adressen) erhoben werden, erfolgt dies, soweit möglich, stets auf freiwilliger
          Basis. Diese Daten werden ohne Ihre ausdrückliche Zustimmung nicht an Dritte weitergegeben. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass die Datenübertragung im Internet (z.B. bei der Kommunikation per E-Mail) Sicherheitslücken aufweisen kann. Ein lückenloser
          Schutz der Daten vor dem Zugriff durch Dritte ist nicht möglich.
        </p>

        <h2>Cookies</h2>
        <p>Die Internetseiten verwenden teilweise so genannte Cookies. Cookies richten auf Ihrem Rechner keinen Schaden an und enthalten keine Viren. Cookies dienen dazu, unser Angebot nutzerfreundlicher, effektiver und sicherer zu machen. Cookies sind kleine
          Textdateien, die auf Ihrem Rechner abgelegt werden und die Ihr Browser speichert. Die meisten der von uns verwendeten Cookies sind so genannte „Session-Cookies“. Sie werden nach Ende Ihres Besuchs automatisch gelöscht. Andere Cookies bleiben
          auf Ihrem Endgerät gespeichert, bis Sie diese löschen. Diese Cookies ermöglichen es uns, Ihren Browser beim nächsten Besuch wiederzuerkennen. Sie können Ihren Browser so einstellen, dass Sie über das Setzen von Cookies informiert werden und
          Cookies nur im Einzelfall erlauben, die Annahme von Cookies für bestimmte Fälle oder generell ausschließen sowie das automatische Löschen der Cookies beim Schließen des Browser aktivieren. Bei der Deaktivierung von Cookies kann die Funktionalität
          dieser Website eingeschränkt sein.</p>

        <h2>Server-Log-Files</h2>
        <p>Der Provider der Seiten erhebt und speichert automatisch Informationen in so genannten Server-Log Files, die Ihr Browser automatisch an uns übermittelt. Dies sind: Browsertyp und Browserversion verwendetes Betriebssystem Referrer URL Hostname
          des zugreifenden Rechners Uhrzeit der Serveranfrage Diese Daten sind nicht bestimmten Personen zuordenbar. Eine Zusammenführung dieser Daten mit anderen Datenquellen wird nicht vorgenommen. Wir behalten uns vor, diese Daten nachträglich zu prüfen,
          wenn uns konkrete Anhaltspunkte für eine rechtswidrige Nutzung bekannt werden.</p>
        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie uns per Kontaktformular Anfragen zukommen lassen, werden Ihre Angaben aus dem Anfrageformular inklusive der von Ihnen dort angegebenen Kontaktdaten zwecks Bearbeitung der Anfrage und für den Fall von Anschlussfragen bei uns gespeichert.
          Diese Daten geben wir nicht ohne Ihre Einwilligung weiter.</p>
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie den auf der Website angebotenen Newsletter beziehen möchten, benötigen wir von Ihnen eine E-Mail-Adresse sowie Informationen, welche uns die Überprüfung gestatten, dass Sie der Inhaber der angegebenen E-Mail-Adresse sind und mit dem Empfang
          des Newsletters einverstanden sind. Weitere Daten werden nicht erhoben. Diese Daten verwenden wir ausschließlich für den Versand der angeforderten Informationen und geben sie nicht an Dritte weiter. Die erteilte Einwilligung zur Speicherung
          der Daten, der E-Mail-Adresse sowie deren Nutzung zum Versand des Newsletters können Sie jederzeit widerrufen, etwa über den "Austragen"-Link im Newsletter.</p>
        <h2>Google Analytics</h2>
        <p>Diese Website nutzt Funktionen des Webanalysedienstes Google Analytics. Anbieter ist die Google Inc., 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043, USA. Google Analytics verwendet so genannte "Cookies". Das sind Textdateien, die auf Ihrem
          Computer gespeichert werden und die eine Analyse der Benutzung der Website durch Sie ermöglichen. Die durch den Cookie erzeugten Informationen über Ihre Benutzung dieser Website werden in der Regel an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen
          und dort gespeichert.</p>
        <p>IP-Anonymisierung<br> Wir haben auf dieser Website die Funktion IP-Anonymisierung aktiviert. Dadurch wird Ihre IP-Adresse von Google innerhalb von Mitgliedstaaten der Europäischen Union oder in anderen Vertragsstaaten des Abkommens über den Europäischen
          Wirtschaftsraum vor der Übermittlung in die USA gekürzt. Nur in Ausnahmefällen wird die volle IP-Adresse an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen und dort gekürzt. Im Auftrag des Betreibers dieser Website wird Google diese Informationen
          benutzen, um Ihre Nutzung der Website auszuwerten, um Reports über die Websiteaktivitäten zusammenzustellen und um weitere mit der Websitenutzung und der Internetnutzung verbundene Dienstleistungen gegenüber dem Websitebetreiber zu erbringen.
          Die im Rahmen von Google Analytics von Ihrem Browser übermittelte IPAdresse wird nicht mit anderen Daten von Google zusammengeführt.</p>
        <p>Browser Plugin<br> Sie können die Speicherung der Cookies durch eine entsprechende Einstellung Ihrer Browser-Software verhindern; wir weisen Sie jedoch darauf hin, dass Sie in diesem Fall gegebenenfalls nicht sämtliche Funktionen dieser Website
          vollumfänglich werden nutzen können. Sie können darüber hinaus die Erfassung der durch den Cookie erzeugten und auf Ihre Nutzung der Website bezogenen Daten (inkl. Ihrer IP-Adresse) an Google sowie die Verarbeitung dieser Daten durch Google
          verhindern, indem Sie das unter dem folgenden Link verfügbare Browser-Plugin herunterladen und installieren: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de
        </p>
        <p>Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung<br> Sie können die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics verhindern, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken. Es wird ein Opt-Out-Cookie gesetzt, der die Erfassung Ihrer Daten bei zukünftigen Besuchen dieser
          Website verhindert: <a href="javascript:gaOptout();">Google Analytics deaktivieren</a> Mehr Informationen zum Umgang mit Nutzerdaten bei Google Analytics finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Google: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6004245?hl=de</p>
        <p>Auftragsverarbeitung<br> Sofern wir mit Google einen Vertrag zur Auftragsdatenverarbeitung abgeschlossen haben, setzen wir die strengen Vorgaben der deutschen Datenschutzbehörden bei der Nutzung von Google Analytics vollständig um.</p>
        <p>Demografische Merkmale bei Google Analytics<br> Diese Website nutzt die Funktion “demografische Merkmale” von Google Analytics. Dadurch können Berichte erstellt werden, die Aussagen zu Alter, Geschlecht und Interessen der Seitenbesucher enthalten.
          Diese Daten stammen aus interessenbezogener Werbung von Google sowie aus Besucherdaten von Drittanbietern. Diese Daten können keiner bestimmten Person zugeordnet werden. Sie können diese Funktion jederzeit über die Anzeigeneinstellungen in Ihrem
          Google-Konto deaktivieren oder die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics wie im Punkt “Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung” dargestellt generell untersagen.</p>
        <h2>Facebook-Plugins</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Plugins des sozialen Netzwerks Facebook, Anbieter Facebook Inc., 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, California 94025, USA, integriert. Die Facebook-Plugins erkennen Sie an dem Facebook-Logo oder dem "Like-Button" ("Gefällt mir")
          auf unserer Seite. Eine Übersicht über die Facebook-Plugins finden Sie hier: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/. Wenn Sie unsere Seiten besuchen, wird über das Plugin eine direkte Verbindung zwischen Ihrem Browser und dem Facebook-Server
          hergestellt. Facebook erhält dadurch die Information, dass Sie mit Ihrer IP-Adresse unsere Seite besucht haben. Wenn Sie den Facebook "Like-Button" anklicken während Sie in Ihrem Facebook-Account eingeloggt sind, können Sie die Inhalte unserer
          Seiten auf Ihrem Facebook-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der übermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung
          durch Facebook erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Facebook unter https://de-de.facebook.com/policy.php. Wenn Sie nicht wünschen, dass Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Facebook-Nutzerkonto
          zuordnen kann, loggen Sie sich bitte aus Ihrem Facebook-Benutzerkonto aus.</p>
        <h2>Instagram</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Funktionen des Dienstes Instagram eingebunden. Diese Funktionen werden angeboten durch die Instagram Inc., 1601 Willow Road, Menlo Park, CA, 94025, USA integriert. Wenn Sie in Ihrem Instagram-Account eingeloggt sind können
          Sie durch Anklicken des Instagram-Buttons die Inhalte unserer Seiten mit Ihrem Instagram-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Instagram den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten
          keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der u?bermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung durch Instagram erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Instagram: https://instagram.com/about/legal/privacy/
        </p>
        <h2>Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Website</h2>
        <p>Für die Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Seite werden neben Ihrem Kommentar auch Angaben zum Zeitpunkt der Erstellung des Kommentars, wenn Sie nicht anonym posten, Ihre E-Mail-Adresse und ggf. der von Ihnen gewählte Nutzername gespeichert. Unsere
          Kommentarfunktion speichert die IP-Adressen der Nutzer, die Kommentare verfassen. Da wir Kommentare auf unserer Seite nicht vor der Freischaltung prüfen, benötigen wir diese Daten, um im Falle von Rechtsverletzungen wie Beleidigungen oder Propaganda
          gegen den Verfasser vorgehen zu können.</p>
        <h2>SSL-Verschlüsselung</h2>
        <p>Diese Seite nutzt aus Gründen der Sicherheit und zum Schutz der Übertragung vertraulicher Inhalte, wie zum Beispiel der Anfragen, die Sie an uns als Seitenbetreiber senden, eine SSL-Verschlüsselung. Eine verschlüsselte Verbindung erkennen Sie
          daran, dass die Adresszeile des Browsers von "http://" auf "https://" wechselt und an dem Schloss-Symbol in Ihrer Browserzeile. Wenn die SSL Verschlüsselung aktiviert ist, können die Daten, die Sie an uns übermitteln, nicht von Dritten mitgelesen
          werden.</p>
        <h2>Recht auf Auskunft, Löschung, Sperrung</h2>
        <p>Sie haben jederzeit das Recht auf unentgeltliche Auskunft über Ihre gespeicherten personenbezogenen Daten, deren Herkunft und Empfänger und den Zweck der Datenverarbeitung sowie ein Recht auf Berichtigung, Sperrung oder Löschung dieser Daten.
          Hierzu sowie zu weiteren Fragen zum Thema personenbezogene Daten können Sie sich jederzeit unter der im Impressum angegebenen Adresse an uns wenden.</p>
        <h2>Unser Widerspruch für Werbe-Mails</h2>
        <p>Der Nutzung von im Rahmen der Impressumspflicht veröffentlichten Kontaktdaten zur Übersendung von nicht ausdrücklich angeforderter Werbung und Informationsmaterialien wird hiermit widersprochen. Die Betreiber der Seiten behalten sich ausdrücklich
          rechtliche Schritte im Falle der unverlangten Zusendung von Werbeinformationen, etwa durch Spam-E-Mails, vor.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the `max-height` to `height`.

**Why?**

In you case the parent container is set to absolute position with no positioned ancestor element so it's relative to the viewport and thus setting percentage with height will work. By doing this you will allow the `max-height` of the child element to be considered because:

> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. The percentage
>   is calculated with respect to the **height** of the generated box's
>   containing block. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-heights)</sup>

So max-height can only work if the height of parent is defined which is not the case of your initial code.

```css
#dataprotection-window {
  width: 50%;
  height: 85%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5%;
  background: #2f2f2f;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#datainner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#dataprotection-window::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#dataprotection-headline h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

#dataprotection-window p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
}

#dataprotection-window h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-margin-after: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="dataprotection-window">
    <div id="datainner">
      <div id="dataprotection-headline">
        <h1>Datenschutz</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="dataprotection-disclaimer">
        <h2>Datenschutz</h2>
        <p>Die Betreiber dieser Seiten nehmen den Schutz Ihrer persönlichen Daten sehr ernst. Wir behandeln Ihre personenbezogenen Daten vertraulich und entsprechend der gesetzlichen Datenschutzvorschriften sowie dieser Datenschutzerklärung. Die Nutzung
          unserer Website ist in der Regel ohne Angabe personenbezogener Daten möglich. Soweit auf unseren Seiten personenbezogene Daten (beispielsweise Name, Anschrift oder E-Mail-Adressen) erhoben werden, erfolgt dies, soweit möglich, stets auf freiwilliger
          Basis. Diese Daten werden ohne Ihre ausdrückliche Zustimmung nicht an Dritte weitergegeben. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass die Datenübertragung im Internet (z.B. bei der Kommunikation per E-Mail) Sicherheitslücken aufweisen kann. Ein lückenloser
          Schutz der Daten vor dem Zugriff durch Dritte ist nicht möglich.
        </p>

        <h2>Cookies</h2>
        <p>Die Internetseiten verwenden teilweise so genannte Cookies. Cookies richten auf Ihrem Rechner keinen Schaden an und enthalten keine Viren. Cookies dienen dazu, unser Angebot nutzerfreundlicher, effektiver und sicherer zu machen. Cookies sind kleine
          Textdateien, die auf Ihrem Rechner abgelegt werden und die Ihr Browser speichert. Die meisten der von uns verwendeten Cookies sind so genannte „Session-Cookies“. Sie werden nach Ende Ihres Besuchs automatisch gelöscht. Andere Cookies bleiben
          auf Ihrem Endgerät gespeichert, bis Sie diese löschen. Diese Cookies ermöglichen es uns, Ihren Browser beim nächsten Besuch wiederzuerkennen. Sie können Ihren Browser so einstellen, dass Sie über das Setzen von Cookies informiert werden und
          Cookies nur im Einzelfall erlauben, die Annahme von Cookies für bestimmte Fälle oder generell ausschließen sowie das automatische Löschen der Cookies beim Schließen des Browser aktivieren. Bei der Deaktivierung von Cookies kann die Funktionalität
          dieser Website eingeschränkt sein.</p>

        <h2>Server-Log-Files</h2>
        <p>Der Provider der Seiten erhebt und speichert automatisch Informationen in so genannten Server-Log Files, die Ihr Browser automatisch an uns übermittelt. Dies sind: Browsertyp und Browserversion verwendetes Betriebssystem Referrer URL Hostname
          des zugreifenden Rechners Uhrzeit der Serveranfrage Diese Daten sind nicht bestimmten Personen zuordenbar. Eine Zusammenführung dieser Daten mit anderen Datenquellen wird nicht vorgenommen. Wir behalten uns vor, diese Daten nachträglich zu prüfen,
          wenn uns konkrete Anhaltspunkte für eine rechtswidrige Nutzung bekannt werden.</p>
        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie uns per Kontaktformular Anfragen zukommen lassen, werden Ihre Angaben aus dem Anfrageformular inklusive der von Ihnen dort angegebenen Kontaktdaten zwecks Bearbeitung der Anfrage und für den Fall von Anschlussfragen bei uns gespeichert.
          Diese Daten geben wir nicht ohne Ihre Einwilligung weiter.</p>
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie den auf der Website angebotenen Newsletter beziehen möchten, benötigen wir von Ihnen eine E-Mail-Adresse sowie Informationen, welche uns die Überprüfung gestatten, dass Sie der Inhaber der angegebenen E-Mail-Adresse sind und mit dem Empfang
          des Newsletters einverstanden sind. Weitere Daten werden nicht erhoben. Diese Daten verwenden wir ausschließlich für den Versand der angeforderten Informationen und geben sie nicht an Dritte weiter. Die erteilte Einwilligung zur Speicherung
          der Daten, der E-Mail-Adresse sowie deren Nutzung zum Versand des Newsletters können Sie jederzeit widerrufen, etwa über den "Austragen"-Link im Newsletter.</p>
        <h2>Google Analytics</h2>
        <p>Diese Website nutzt Funktionen des Webanalysedienstes Google Analytics. Anbieter ist die Google Inc., 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043, USA. Google Analytics verwendet so genannte "Cookies". Das sind Textdateien, die auf Ihrem
          Computer gespeichert werden und die eine Analyse der Benutzung der Website durch Sie ermöglichen. Die durch den Cookie erzeugten Informationen über Ihre Benutzung dieser Website werden in der Regel an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen
          und dort gespeichert.</p>
        <p>IP-Anonymisierung<br> Wir haben auf dieser Website die Funktion IP-Anonymisierung aktiviert. Dadurch wird Ihre IP-Adresse von Google innerhalb von Mitgliedstaaten der Europäischen Union oder in anderen Vertragsstaaten des Abkommens über den Europäischen
          Wirtschaftsraum vor der Übermittlung in die USA gekürzt. Nur in Ausnahmefällen wird die volle IP-Adresse an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen und dort gekürzt. Im Auftrag des Betreibers dieser Website wird Google diese Informationen
          benutzen, um Ihre Nutzung der Website auszuwerten, um Reports über die Websiteaktivitäten zusammenzustellen und um weitere mit der Websitenutzung und der Internetnutzung verbundene Dienstleistungen gegenüber dem Websitebetreiber zu erbringen.
          Die im Rahmen von Google Analytics von Ihrem Browser übermittelte IPAdresse wird nicht mit anderen Daten von Google zusammengeführt.</p>
        <p>Browser Plugin<br> Sie können die Speicherung der Cookies durch eine entsprechende Einstellung Ihrer Browser-Software verhindern; wir weisen Sie jedoch darauf hin, dass Sie in diesem Fall gegebenenfalls nicht sämtliche Funktionen dieser Website
          vollumfänglich werden nutzen können. Sie können darüber hinaus die Erfassung der durch den Cookie erzeugten und auf Ihre Nutzung der Website bezogenen Daten (inkl. Ihrer IP-Adresse) an Google sowie die Verarbeitung dieser Daten durch Google
          verhindern, indem Sie das unter dem folgenden Link verfügbare Browser-Plugin herunterladen und installieren: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de
        </p>
        <p>Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung<br> Sie können die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics verhindern, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken. Es wird ein Opt-Out-Cookie gesetzt, der die Erfassung Ihrer Daten bei zukünftigen Besuchen dieser
          Website verhindert: <a href="javascript:gaOptout();">Google Analytics deaktivieren</a> Mehr Informationen zum Umgang mit Nutzerdaten bei Google Analytics finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Google: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6004245?hl=de</p>
        <p>Auftragsverarbeitung<br> Sofern wir mit Google einen Vertrag zur Auftragsdatenverarbeitung abgeschlossen haben, setzen wir die strengen Vorgaben der deutschen Datenschutzbehörden bei der Nutzung von Google Analytics vollständig um.</p>
        <p>Demografische Merkmale bei Google Analytics<br> Diese Website nutzt die Funktion “demografische Merkmale” von Google Analytics. Dadurch können Berichte erstellt werden, die Aussagen zu Alter, Geschlecht und Interessen der Seitenbesucher enthalten.
          Diese Daten stammen aus interessenbezogener Werbung von Google sowie aus Besucherdaten von Drittanbietern. Diese Daten können keiner bestimmten Person zugeordnet werden. Sie können diese Funktion jederzeit über die Anzeigeneinstellungen in Ihrem
          Google-Konto deaktivieren oder die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics wie im Punkt “Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung” dargestellt generell untersagen.</p>
        <h2>Facebook-Plugins</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Plugins des sozialen Netzwerks Facebook, Anbieter Facebook Inc., 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, California 94025, USA, integriert. Die Facebook-Plugins erkennen Sie an dem Facebook-Logo oder dem "Like-Button" ("Gefällt mir")
          auf unserer Seite. Eine Übersicht über die Facebook-Plugins finden Sie hier: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/. Wenn Sie unsere Seiten besuchen, wird über das Plugin eine direkte Verbindung zwischen Ihrem Browser und dem Facebook-Server
          hergestellt. Facebook erhält dadurch die Information, dass Sie mit Ihrer IP-Adresse unsere Seite besucht haben. Wenn Sie den Facebook "Like-Button" anklicken während Sie in Ihrem Facebook-Account eingeloggt sind, können Sie die Inhalte unserer
          Seiten auf Ihrem Facebook-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der übermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung
          durch Facebook erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Facebook unter https://de-de.facebook.com/policy.php. Wenn Sie nicht wünschen, dass Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Facebook-Nutzerkonto
          zuordnen kann, loggen Sie sich bitte aus Ihrem Facebook-Benutzerkonto aus.</p>
        <h2>Instagram</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Funktionen des Dienstes Instagram eingebunden. Diese Funktionen werden angeboten durch die Instagram Inc., 1601 Willow Road, Menlo Park, CA, 94025, USA integriert. Wenn Sie in Ihrem Instagram-Account eingeloggt sind können
          Sie durch Anklicken des Instagram-Buttons die Inhalte unserer Seiten mit Ihrem Instagram-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Instagram den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten
          keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der u?bermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung durch Instagram erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Instagram: https://instagram.com/about/legal/privacy/
        </p>
        <h2>Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Website</h2>
        <p>Für die Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Seite werden neben Ihrem Kommentar auch Angaben zum Zeitpunkt der Erstellung des Kommentars, wenn Sie nicht anonym posten, Ihre E-Mail-Adresse und ggf. der von Ihnen gewählte Nutzername gespeichert. Unsere
          Kommentarfunktion speichert die IP-Adressen der Nutzer, die Kommentare verfassen. Da wir Kommentare auf unserer Seite nicht vor der Freischaltung prüfen, benötigen wir diese Daten, um im Falle von Rechtsverletzungen wie Beleidigungen oder Propaganda
          gegen den Verfasser vorgehen zu können.</p>
        <h2>SSL-Verschlüsselung</h2>
        <p>Diese Seite nutzt aus Gründen der Sicherheit und zum Schutz der Übertragung vertraulicher Inhalte, wie zum Beispiel der Anfragen, die Sie an uns als Seitenbetreiber senden, eine SSL-Verschlüsselung. Eine verschlüsselte Verbindung erkennen Sie
          daran, dass die Adresszeile des Browsers von "http://" auf "https://" wechselt und an dem Schloss-Symbol in Ihrer Browserzeile. Wenn die SSL Verschlüsselung aktiviert ist, können die Daten, die Sie an uns übermitteln, nicht von Dritten mitgelesen
          werden.</p>
        <h2>Recht auf Auskunft, Löschung, Sperrung</h2>
        <p>Sie haben jederzeit das Recht auf unentgeltliche Auskunft über Ihre gespeicherten personenbezogenen Daten, deren Herkunft und Empfänger und den Zweck der Datenverarbeitung sowie ein Recht auf Berichtigung, Sperrung oder Löschung dieser Daten.
          Hierzu sowie zu weiteren Fragen zum Thema personenbezogene Daten können Sie sich jederzeit unter der im Impressum angegebenen Adresse an uns wenden.</p>
        <h2>Unser Widerspruch für Werbe-Mails</h2>
        <p>Der Nutzung von im Rahmen der Impressumspflicht veröffentlichten Kontaktdaten zur Übersendung von nicht ausdrücklich angeforderter Werbung und Informationsmaterialien wird hiermit widersprochen. Die Betreiber der Seiten behalten sich ausdrücklich
          rechtliche Schritte im Falle der unverlangten Zusendung von Werbeinformationen, etwa durch Spam-E-Mails, vor.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Temani, that's probably the easiest solution! I tried a few options by playing around but missed this one! Thank you!!

Comment: I had to slightly amend the div order and the solution doesnt work anymore. Would you also have a quick fix for this? https://jsfiddle.net/6kuc7opw/ Hope you still see this

Comment: @AlphaX because now you made the title to be outside and thus taking height ... so you need to consider it's height in the max calculation

Comment: @AlphaX here is a quick fix https://jsfiddle.net/6kuc7opw/3/ but if it will become complicate i would probably go with anther solution ;)

Comment: yeah I thought hindsight it doesnt make sense to have the title scrolled. I will play around with the calc and some bottom padding. Your solution was really helpful (like always!) Thank you so much Temani!!

Comment: @AlphaX yes but at least now you know two things, why the max-height is not working [i added more explanation] and also the use of calc :) then you can consider other solution that are more flexible also, like the one of C-Gyr with flex

Answer (score 2):

You may use here the display:flex properties:

```
#dataprotection-window {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 85%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5%;
  background: #2f2f2f;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: flex;/* let flex do the math for you */
}

#datainner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;/* fills up entire room avalaible*/
  overflow: auto;/* show scrollbar when needed */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agz8krxf/8/ or demo below

```css
#dataprotection-window {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 85%;
  padding: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 5%;
  background: #2f2f2f;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: flex;
}

#datainner {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#dataprotection-window::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

#dataprotection-headline h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2f2f2f, #fff, #2f2f2f);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

#dataprotection-window p {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: justify;
}

#dataprotection-window h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-margin-after: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="dataprotection-window">
    <div id="datainner">
      <div id="dataprotection-headline">
        <h1>Datenschutz</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="dataprotection-disclaimer">
        <h2>Datenschutz</h2>
        <p>Die Betreiber dieser Seiten nehmen den Schutz Ihrer persönlichen Daten sehr ernst. Wir behandeln Ihre personenbezogenen Daten vertraulich und entsprechend der gesetzlichen Datenschutzvorschriften sowie dieser Datenschutzerklärung. Die Nutzung
          unserer Website ist in der Regel ohne Angabe personenbezogener Daten möglich. Soweit auf unseren Seiten personenbezogene Daten (beispielsweise Name, Anschrift oder E-Mail-Adressen) erhoben werden, erfolgt dies, soweit möglich, stets auf freiwilliger
          Basis. Diese Daten werden ohne Ihre ausdrückliche Zustimmung nicht an Dritte weitergegeben. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass die Datenübertragung im Internet (z.B. bei der Kommunikation per E-Mail) Sicherheitslücken aufweisen kann. Ein lückenloser
          Schutz der Daten vor dem Zugriff durch Dritte ist nicht möglich.
        </p>

        <h2>Cookies</h2>
        <p>Die Internetseiten verwenden teilweise so genannte Cookies. Cookies richten auf Ihrem Rechner keinen Schaden an und enthalten keine Viren. Cookies dienen dazu, unser Angebot nutzerfreundlicher, effektiver und sicherer zu machen. Cookies sind kleine
          Textdateien, die auf Ihrem Rechner abgelegt werden und die Ihr Browser speichert. Die meisten der von uns verwendeten Cookies sind so genannte „Session-Cookies“. Sie werden nach Ende Ihres Besuchs automatisch gelöscht. Andere Cookies bleiben
          auf Ihrem Endgerät gespeichert, bis Sie diese löschen. Diese Cookies ermöglichen es uns, Ihren Browser beim nächsten Besuch wiederzuerkennen. Sie können Ihren Browser so einstellen, dass Sie über das Setzen von Cookies informiert werden und
          Cookies nur im Einzelfall erlauben, die Annahme von Cookies für bestimmte Fälle oder generell ausschließen sowie das automatische Löschen der Cookies beim Schließen des Browser aktivieren. Bei der Deaktivierung von Cookies kann die Funktionalität
          dieser Website eingeschränkt sein.</p>

        <h2>Server-Log-Files</h2>
        <p>Der Provider der Seiten erhebt und speichert automatisch Informationen in so genannten Server-Log Files, die Ihr Browser automatisch an uns übermittelt. Dies sind: Browsertyp und Browserversion verwendetes Betriebssystem Referrer URL Hostname
          des zugreifenden Rechners Uhrzeit der Serveranfrage Diese Daten sind nicht bestimmten Personen zuordenbar. Eine Zusammenführung dieser Daten mit anderen Datenquellen wird nicht vorgenommen. Wir behalten uns vor, diese Daten nachträglich zu prüfen,
          wenn uns konkrete Anhaltspunkte für eine rechtswidrige Nutzung bekannt werden.</p>
        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie uns per Kontaktformular Anfragen zukommen lassen, werden Ihre Angaben aus dem Anfrageformular inklusive der von Ihnen dort angegebenen Kontaktdaten zwecks Bearbeitung der Anfrage und für den Fall von Anschlussfragen bei uns gespeichert.
          Diese Daten geben wir nicht ohne Ihre Einwilligung weiter.</p>
        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
        <p>Wenn Sie den auf der Website angebotenen Newsletter beziehen möchten, benötigen wir von Ihnen eine E-Mail-Adresse sowie Informationen, welche uns die Überprüfung gestatten, dass Sie der Inhaber der angegebenen E-Mail-Adresse sind und mit dem Empfang
          des Newsletters einverstanden sind. Weitere Daten werden nicht erhoben. Diese Daten verwenden wir ausschließlich für den Versand der angeforderten Informationen und geben sie nicht an Dritte weiter. Die erteilte Einwilligung zur Speicherung
          der Daten, der E-Mail-Adresse sowie deren Nutzung zum Versand des Newsletters können Sie jederzeit widerrufen, etwa über den "Austragen"-Link im Newsletter.</p>
        <h2>Google Analytics</h2>
        <p>Diese Website nutzt Funktionen des Webanalysedienstes Google Analytics. Anbieter ist die Google Inc., 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043, USA. Google Analytics verwendet so genannte "Cookies". Das sind Textdateien, die auf Ihrem
          Computer gespeichert werden und die eine Analyse der Benutzung der Website durch Sie ermöglichen. Die durch den Cookie erzeugten Informationen über Ihre Benutzung dieser Website werden in der Regel an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen
          und dort gespeichert.</p>
        <p>IP-Anonymisierung<br> Wir haben auf dieser Website die Funktion IP-Anonymisierung aktiviert. Dadurch wird Ihre IP-Adresse von Google innerhalb von Mitgliedstaaten der Europäischen Union oder in anderen Vertragsstaaten des Abkommens über den Europäischen
          Wirtschaftsraum vor der Übermittlung in die USA gekürzt. Nur in Ausnahmefällen wird die volle IP-Adresse an einen Server von Google in den USA übertragen und dort gekürzt. Im Auftrag des Betreibers dieser Website wird Google diese Informationen
          benutzen, um Ihre Nutzung der Website auszuwerten, um Reports über die Websiteaktivitäten zusammenzustellen und um weitere mit der Websitenutzung und der Internetnutzung verbundene Dienstleistungen gegenüber dem Websitebetreiber zu erbringen.
          Die im Rahmen von Google Analytics von Ihrem Browser übermittelte IPAdresse wird nicht mit anderen Daten von Google zusammengeführt.</p>
        <p>Browser Plugin<br> Sie können die Speicherung der Cookies durch eine entsprechende Einstellung Ihrer Browser-Software verhindern; wir weisen Sie jedoch darauf hin, dass Sie in diesem Fall gegebenenfalls nicht sämtliche Funktionen dieser Website
          vollumfänglich werden nutzen können. Sie können darüber hinaus die Erfassung der durch den Cookie erzeugten und auf Ihre Nutzung der Website bezogenen Daten (inkl. Ihrer IP-Adresse) an Google sowie die Verarbeitung dieser Daten durch Google
          verhindern, indem Sie das unter dem folgenden Link verfügbare Browser-Plugin herunterladen und installieren: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=de
        </p>
        <p>Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung<br> Sie können die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics verhindern, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken. Es wird ein Opt-Out-Cookie gesetzt, der die Erfassung Ihrer Daten bei zukünftigen Besuchen dieser
          Website verhindert: <a href="javascript:gaOptout();">Google Analytics deaktivieren</a> Mehr Informationen zum Umgang mit Nutzerdaten bei Google Analytics finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Google: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6004245?hl=de</p>
        <p>Auftragsverarbeitung<br> Sofern wir mit Google einen Vertrag zur Auftragsdatenverarbeitung abgeschlossen haben, setzen wir die strengen Vorgaben der deutschen Datenschutzbehörden bei der Nutzung von Google Analytics vollständig um.</p>
        <p>Demografische Merkmale bei Google Analytics<br> Diese Website nutzt die Funktion “demografische Merkmale” von Google Analytics. Dadurch können Berichte erstellt werden, die Aussagen zu Alter, Geschlecht und Interessen der Seitenbesucher enthalten.
          Diese Daten stammen aus interessenbezogener Werbung von Google sowie aus Besucherdaten von Drittanbietern. Diese Daten können keiner bestimmten Person zugeordnet werden. Sie können diese Funktion jederzeit über die Anzeigeneinstellungen in Ihrem
          Google-Konto deaktivieren oder die Erfassung Ihrer Daten durch Google Analytics wie im Punkt “Widerspruch gegen Datenerfassung” dargestellt generell untersagen.</p>
        <h2>Facebook-Plugins</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Plugins des sozialen Netzwerks Facebook, Anbieter Facebook Inc., 1 Hacker Way, Menlo Park, California 94025, USA, integriert. Die Facebook-Plugins erkennen Sie an dem Facebook-Logo oder dem "Like-Button" ("Gefällt mir")
          auf unserer Seite. Eine Übersicht über die Facebook-Plugins finden Sie hier: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/. Wenn Sie unsere Seiten besuchen, wird über das Plugin eine direkte Verbindung zwischen Ihrem Browser und dem Facebook-Server
          hergestellt. Facebook erhält dadurch die Information, dass Sie mit Ihrer IP-Adresse unsere Seite besucht haben. Wenn Sie den Facebook "Like-Button" anklicken während Sie in Ihrem Facebook-Account eingeloggt sind, können Sie die Inhalte unserer
          Seiten auf Ihrem Facebook-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der übermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung
          durch Facebook erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Facebook unter https://de-de.facebook.com/policy.php. Wenn Sie nicht wünschen, dass Facebook den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Facebook-Nutzerkonto
          zuordnen kann, loggen Sie sich bitte aus Ihrem Facebook-Benutzerkonto aus.</p>
        <h2>Instagram</h2>
        <p>Auf unseren Seiten sind Funktionen des Dienstes Instagram eingebunden. Diese Funktionen werden angeboten durch die Instagram Inc., 1601 Willow Road, Menlo Park, CA, 94025, USA integriert. Wenn Sie in Ihrem Instagram-Account eingeloggt sind können
          Sie durch Anklicken des Instagram-Buttons die Inhalte unserer Seiten mit Ihrem Instagram-Profil verlinken. Dadurch kann Instagram den Besuch unserer Seiten Ihrem Benutzerkonto zuordnen. Wir weisen darauf hin, dass wir als Anbieter der Seiten
          keine Kenntnis vom Inhalt der u?bermittelten Daten sowie deren Nutzung durch Instagram erhalten. Weitere Informationen hierzu finden Sie in der Datenschutzerklärung von Instagram: https://instagram.com/about/legal/privacy/
        </p>
        <h2>Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Website</h2>
        <p>Für die Kommentarfunktion auf dieser Seite werden neben Ihrem Kommentar auch Angaben zum Zeitpunkt der Erstellung des Kommentars, wenn Sie nicht anonym posten, Ihre E-Mail-Adresse und ggf. der von Ihnen gewählte Nutzername gespeichert. Unsere
          Kommentarfunktion speichert die IP-Adressen der Nutzer, die Kommentare verfassen. Da wir Kommentare auf unserer Seite nicht vor der Freischaltung prüfen, benötigen wir diese Daten, um im Falle von Rechtsverletzungen wie Beleidigungen oder Propaganda
          gegen den Verfasser vorgehen zu können.</p>
        <h2>SSL-Verschlüsselung</h2>
        <p>Diese Seite nutzt aus Gründen der Sicherheit und zum Schutz der Übertragung vertraulicher Inhalte, wie zum Beispiel der Anfragen, die Sie an uns als Seitenbetreiber senden, eine SSL-Verschlüsselung. Eine verschlüsselte Verbindung erkennen Sie
          daran, dass die Adresszeile des Browsers von "http://" auf "https://" wechselt und an dem Schloss-Symbol in Ihrer Browserzeile. Wenn die SSL Verschlüsselung aktiviert ist, können die Daten, die Sie an uns übermitteln, nicht von Dritten mitgelesen
          werden.
        </p>
        <h2>Recht auf Auskunft, Löschung, Sperrung</h2>
        <p>Sie haben jederzeit das Recht auf unentgeltliche Auskunft über Ihre gespeicherten personenbezogenen Daten, deren Herkunft und Empfänger und den Zweck der Datenverarbeitung sowie ein Recht auf Berichtigung, Sperrung oder Löschung dieser Daten.
          Hierzu sowie zu weiteren Fragen zum Thema personenbezogene Daten können Sie sich jederzeit unter der im Impressum angegebenen Adresse an uns wenden.</p>
        <h2>Unser Widerspruch für Werbe-Mails</h2>
        <p>Der Nutzung von im Rahmen der Impressumspflicht veröffentlichten Kontaktdaten zur Übersendung von nicht ausdrücklich angeforderter Werbung und Informationsmaterialien wird hiermit widersprochen. Die Betreiber der Seiten behalten sich ausdrücklich
          rechtliche Schritte im Falle der unverlangten Zusendung von Werbeinformationen, etwa durch Spam-E-Mails, vor.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: A M A Z I N G!! Thanks G-Cyr! Could you explain what the display: flex property does in this case? I would love to understand this simple and effective solution!

Comment: @AlphaX the flexbox is a technique to create some layout ... in this case the important part is the `flex:1` that allow the content to expand to all the area (equivalent to your max-height:100%) .. but to make this more *correct* i would add `flex-direction:column` .. it won't have effect here because it's one element but it will become relevant if you will have more  ... also you won't see the effect of `flex:1` as the content is already taking more space then it's parent

Answer (score 0):

Just use overflow:auto on parent div. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/farhan2056/mgw0fu2n/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        //long content
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px;
  height:100vh;
  background:#2f2f2f;
  overflow:auto;
}
.child{
  color:#fff;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Farhan, I had this before but the scrollbar isnt inside the parent div and hence it doesnt look nice, so I need the child to be scrollable

Comment: the scrollbar is inside the parent div.